# Question mark in the beginning of line in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Why when I use a question mark at the beginning of a line it makes it into a `String`?

For example:

```
?a
# => "a"

?1
# => "1"

?(
# => "("

?a + "b"
# => "ab"
```

When I use more than 1 character it raises error:

```
?ab
# SyntaxError (syntax error, unexpected '?')
```

Why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html):

> There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding

```
?a       #=> "a"
?abc     #=> SyntaxError
?\n      #=> "\n"
?\s      #=> " "
?\\      #=> "\\"
?\u{41}  #=> "A"
?\C-a    #=> "\x01"
?\M-a    #=> "\xE1"
?\M-\C-a #=> "\x81"
?\C-\M-a #=> "\x81", same as above
?あ      #=> "あ"
```